# SQL query html table format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

How to echo the left column table to "Daily" "Monthly" and "Yearly"? It currently displays repeatedly because the results of SQL queries on the right side are 3 items.

```
$ID = get_current_user_id();
global $wpdb;
if(isset($_GET["view_data"])){
   $SubmissionID = $_GET["view_data"];
   $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}myTable WHERE user_id = {$ID} AND `key` IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')", OBJECT );
    if(isset($_GET["form_name"])) echo "<h4>YOUR REVIEW ON {$_GET["form_name"]}</h4>";

    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($results as $result) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo    "<p>test1</p>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo    $result->value;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
    
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<h4><a href='?view_all'>Back to List</a></h4>";
}
```

The current output of my code:

| test1 | dynamic_data_1 |
| --- | --- |
| test1 | dynamic_data_2 |
| test1 | dynamic_data_3 |

The output I need:

| Daily | dynamic_data_1 |
| --- | --- |
| Monthly | dynamic_data_2 |
| Yearly | dynamic_data_3 |

Comment: what do you want it to be called?

Comment: Since the dynamic_data on the right side are pulling from the Database table. I just need to rename the left column in HTML format without repeating.

Comment: rename it Test1, test2, test3 etc?

Comment: Yes, how can I achieve that? is that possible in foreach()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a counter:

```
$ID = get_current_user_id();
global $wpdb;
if(isset($_GET["view_data"])){
   $SubmissionID = $_GET["view_data"];
   $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}myTable WHERE user_id = {$ID} AND `key` IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')", OBJECT );
    if(isset($_GET["form_name"])) echo "<h4>YOUR REVIEW ON {$_GET["form_name"]}</h4>";
    $count = 0;

    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($results as $result) {
    $count++;
    $title = 'DEFAULT Title';
        if( $count == 1 ){
            $title = 'Daily';
        }
        elseif( $count == 2 ){
            $title = 'Monthly';
        }
        elseif( $count == 3 ){
            $title = 'Yearly';
        }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo    "<p>" . $title ."</p>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo    $result->value;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
    
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<h4><a href='?view_all'>Back to List</a></h4>";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the output is not just test1, test2, etc. But completely different. I'm okay to use a different approach just to rename the left column values individually.

Comment: you can name it based on the results as well. what is being returned in `result`?

Comment: I'd like to change the left column values to "Daily" "Monthly" and "Yearly" instead. But I'm not sure if counter can do that? Thank you.

Comment: is it always 3 results?

Comment: Not necessarily 3. It depends on the  echo "$result->value"

Comment: so is there another option to see what data is coming through? like how do you know if its daily, monthly etc?

Comment: No, I just want to echo in plain HTML the words Daily Monthy and Yearly. Is that possible inside foreach() loop? I edited my questions.